# Error in the z3 python code

Tags: python, z3

The following code terminates after 8 iterations (while it should iterate 14 times) why?

The code encodes a linear hybrid automata, it should run for the designated number of iterations but doesn't.

```
from z3 import *
x,t,t1,t2,x_next=Reals ('x t t1 t2 x_next')

location=[None]
location='off'
x=20
t1=0

s=Solver()
#set_option(precision=10)
k=14
for   i in range(k):

  print location 
  if location=='off':
      s.add((10*x_next)>=(3*t1)-(3*t2)+(10*x),(10*x_next)<=(10*x)-(t2-t1),x_next>=18,(t2-t1)>0)
  elif location=='on':
      s.add(10*x_next>=(t2-t1)+(10*x),(5*x_next)<=(5*x)+(t2-t1),x_next<=22,(t2-t1)>0)


  if  [location=='off' and x_next<19] :
      location='on'
  elif [location=='on' and x_next>21]:
       location='off'

  if s.check()==unsat:
      break

  m=s.model()
  #print s.check()
  print i
  print location
  print s.model()

  print "value of x_next"
  print m[x_next].as_decimal(10)

  x=m[x_next]
  t1=m[t2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program stops because the set of assertions is unsatisfiable after iteration 8, and in your loop you have the statements:

```
if s.check()==unsat:
    break
```

In the first iteration you add the assertion:

```
10*x_next <= 200 - t2 - 0
```

In the last iteration, you add:

```
10*x_next >= t2 - Q(40,3) + 10*Q(56,3),
t2 - Q(40,3) > 0
```

where, the command `Q(a, b)` is used to create the rational number `a/b`.
That is, `t1` is `40/3` and `x` is `56/3` at iteration 8.
The three assertions above are unsatisfiable. The first two imply that `t2 <= 40/3`, and the last `t2 > 40/3`.

BTW, the following statement seems to be incorrect. That is, I do not believe it reflects your intention. Note that, this is orthogonal problem.

```
if  [location=='off' and x_next<19] :
```

The expression `x_next<19` does not evaluate to `True` or `False`. It creates the Z3 (symbolic) expression `x_next < 19`. I believe, you want to evaluate whether this expression is true in a model `m`. If that is the case, you should write:

```
if  location=='off' and is_true(m.evaluate(x_next<19)) :
```

The command `m.evaluate(t)` evaluates the expression `t` in the model `m`. The result is a Z3 expression. The function `is_true(t)` returns `True` if `t` is the Z3 expression true.

Comment: can the satisfiability of the first one be checked independently from the last two assertion? Infact They have to be checked indep. is his correct  if  [location=='off' and m[x_next]<19] :?????

Comment: Regarding the first question, your loop is accumulating all assertions. That is, you are checking the satisfiability of all of them in each iteration. If you want to check at iteration `i` just the formula created at iteration `i`, then you should create a new solver at each iteration. That is, you should put `s = Solver()` inside the for-loop.

Comment: Regarding the second question, `m[x_next]` returns a Z3 expression. It may be a numeral, but it is not a Python integer. Since, `x_next` is a real, `m[x_next]` may not even be an integer. Thus, converting it to a Python integer is not a good idea. Converting it into a float is also problematic since we may lose precision. Moreover, since `m[x_next]` is a Z3 expression, then `m[x_next]<19` is also a Z3 (symbolic) expression.

Comment: thanx the code is now in running condition atleast. Can i make this if else structure as part of the assertions?

Comment: Yes, you can. However, you have to create Z3 variables to represent `location` and `location_next`. Assuming you are using `True` and `False` to represent `on` and `off`. We can encode the `location` update as `location_next == If(And(Not(location), x_next < 19), True, If(And(location, x_next > 21), False, location))`. I created `location` and `location_next` using command `location, location_next = Bools('location location_next')`

Comment: There seems to be an issue of precision.How to improve upon that?

Comment: What do you mean by precision? Z3 uses multiple precision arithmetic.

Comment: this might be my lack of understanding of Z3, and i was just wondering whether it is possible to represent a real  number as a floating point?

Comment: In continuation to our yesterday discussion.... i want that location be False at first iteration , so how to add such constraint? i tried with location== If(i==0,False,location), but since i is constant here, it returned an error.

Comment: Z3 represent real numbers using arbitrary precision rationals or algebraic numbers. So, there is no imprecision due to floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Regarding the initialization, you can add `location=BoolVal(False)` after the initialization of `x` and `t` in the script above. The expression `BoolVal(False)` creates the Z3 expression corresponding to the `False` Boolean value. Note that, it is also ok in the example above to initialize location as `location = False`. That is, using a Python Boolean value. The Z3 (Python) API automatically converts Python Boolean values to Z3 Boolean expressions when needed.

Comment: for   i in range(k):
  s=Solver()
       
  s.add(Or(And((10*x_next)>=(3*t1)-(3*t2)+(10*x),(10*x_next)<=(10*x)-(t2-t1),x_next>=18,(t2-t1)>0,Not(location_next),Not(location)),
           And((10*x_next)>=(t2-t1)+(10*x),(5*x_next)<=(5*x)+(t2-t1),x_next<=22,(t2-t1)>0,location_next,location)),
            location_next==If(And(Not(location),x_next<19),True,If(And(location,x_next>21),False,location)))
   
this loop now with location initialized with "False" only runs for 2  iterations???

Comment: Please create a different question at stackoverflow. Consider also accepting the answer for the original question. Non-accepted answer are seen as unsolved issues, and other users may assume the question was not answered.